# Issue collision coordinates Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a coordinates issue,I'll explain:

I have a tiledmap that I render by OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer and OrthographicCamera and I have this code in the create method:

```
map=new TmxMapLoader().load("Map.tmx");
this.renderer=new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
this.camera=new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
this.camera.translate(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
this.camera.update();
```

in the render method:

```
this.renderer.setView(camera);
this.renderer.render();
camera.update();
```

I have also a sprite that draw by Batch always in the render method:

```
batchM.begin();
sprite.draw(batchM);
batchM.end();
```

Always in the render method I extract all MapObject from Tiledmap and I check if them hit the sprite:

```
 MapObjects collisionObjects =  map.getLayers().get("objects").getObjects();
        for(MapObject object : collisionObjects) {

               if (object instanceof RectangleMapObject) {
                   RectangleMapObject rect = ((RectangleMapObject) object);


                  Vector3 coo=camera.project(new
    Vector3(rect.getRectangle().x,rect.getRectangle().y,0));


                    com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle Sprite= sprite.getBoundingRectangle();
                    com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle Map=new com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle(coo.x,coo.y,32,32);

                   //TEST
                   System.out.println("SPRITE X: "+Sprite.x+" Y: "+Sprite.y);
                   System.out.println("Object X: "+Map.x+" Y: "+Map.y);

                    if(Intersector.intersectRectangles(Sprite, Map, Sprite)) System.out.println("HIT");
                    }

                }
```

My problem is this:

if I remain the normal window size (ie the size when I start the program) collisions are detected with precision.

while if I decrease or increase the size of the window, collisions are detected imprecisely.

In particular I noticed this oddity:

when I extract the objects from the map, I display the coordinates of the object and sprite, and I noticed that the coordinates of the sprite remain unchanged while those of the object change and I can not explain why.

Thank you very much for your time and help

**EDIT:**

Example of changing coordinates:

starting window size:

SPRITE X: 310.0 Y: 270.0

Object X: 384.0 Y: 352.0

HIT

Then I don't move the sprite but change only the windows size(increase) and I get this:

SPRITE X: 310.0 Y: 270.0

Object X: 586.2 Y: 540.4667

Comment: Try it without the camera.project as this is projecting your world co-ordinates to screen co-ordinates "Vector3 coo", hence when you change screen size you change the position of Object X.

Comment: Hi,yes doing as you say the problem is solved but there is still another problem, what's in the camera (the tiledmap) represents the background so if I scroll down (thus move the y coordinate of the camera) the collision is not detected

Comment: gently you could give me a helping hand.